# compiling a visual studio solution file

Tags: c#, compilation

I have downloaded a c# project and was told to compile it to make a DLL files !! can u tell me how !!? 
I'm using VS2008 
 thank u

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio?
Or are you using the commandline compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you open the project and check the Project Type.  If the project type is `Class Library`, then click Build->Build Solution.

If you are compiling from the Command Line, then I'd recommend this [link](http://www.charlespetzold.com/key/CommandLine.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio:

Right click Project name (in Solution Explorer), select `Properties` and in the `Output Type` combobox select `Class Library.`